# supremum norm and convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Suppose that for some $\epsilon$ > 0,

$\max_{t \in [0,n]} |f(t)|$ <  $\epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Is it then true that 
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\max_{t \in [0,n]} |f(t)|)_n \rightarrow\sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} |f(t)|?$$

The sequence $a_n = \max_{t \in [0,n]} |f(t)|)_n$ is non-decreasing for $n$ and $[0,\infty) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,n]$ .

Can you please give a rigorous proof or a counter example if it doesn't hold?

Comment: This is true. Your $\epsilon$ assumption can even be lifted:
 it still holds, the limit being possibly infinite.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \in \def\N{\mathbb N}\N$ let $a_n := \max_{t \in [0,n]} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{f(t)}$. Then $0\le a_n \le a_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \N$. So $a := \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n  =\sup_n a_n \in [0,\infty]$ exists. We will show that $a = \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}$:

On one hand, for every $n$ 
$$ a_n = \max_{t\in [0,n]} \abs{f(t)} \le \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}, $$
hence $a = \sup_n a_n \le \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}$.

On the other hand, for every $M < \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}$ there is $t_M \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\abs{f(t_M)} > M$ by the definition of supremum. Choose $n_M \in \N$ with $n_M > t_M$, then 
$$ a \ge a_{n_M} \ge \abs{f(t_M)} > M $$
As $M < \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}$ was arbitrary, 
$$ a \le \sup_{t\in [0,\infty)} \abs{f(t)}. $$